# How to access the icon set of the current system theme?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, icons

I'm writing a bash script that uses notify-send (from the notify-osd package) to show popup notifications to the user, e.g. if there is an error during runtime. These popups can be decorated with icons, like so:

```
notify-send -i $icon $headline $message
```

In order to make my script as lean as possible, I want to use the default icons that come with the system. So far, I have resorted to hard-coded filenames, like so:

```
icon="/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/status/48/dialog-error.png"
```

This is obviously a pretty bad solution, since the icon depends on a theme that may not be installed on a given system (in the example above, it's the "Mint Y" theme). I'm looking for a way to tell my script: "Ask the system for the error icon in the currently-set icon theme, and use that."

The question is: how do I do that?

Comment: This is something specific to the particular window manager you're using.

Comment: Apologies, but could you be a bit more specific? _What exactly_ is specific to the window manager in use? Requesting the current theme? Requesting a generic icon? Where can I read up on that?

Comment: I mean desktop environments like Gnome, KDE, etc. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment

Comment: So there is no "cross-DE" way to do this? Ok... let's say I want to do this in Gnome (and Gnome-based DEs such as Cinnamon)... how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't specify anything like a path. You should be specifying a generic filename fragment, and letting the system search for the best value for you.

So, if there is a size or filetype or something in the filename, drop it, and do not specify the leading path.

Use something like `notify-send -i info test` or `notify-send -i error test` ...

Or `notify-send -i printer-error test`, which will find something like `/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/256x256/status/printer-error.png` under the hood.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick for me. I'm now using notify-send -i error | settings | info ... Works like a charm! :)

Comment: Are these generic names listed somewhere so that I do not have to take random shots at getting the right key word for every new notification?